# Dectecting whether a Circle intersects with a Rectangle on its top half or bottom half in LibGDX

Tags: java, libgdx

Using LibGDX, I have a Circle object that collides with a Rectangle object. I detect this collision using the Intersector class included with Libgdx, as so:

```
 if(Intersector.overlaps(circle, rectangle)){
        do something
    }
```

This detection works fine, but I am wondering if there is a way to detect whether the circle has collided with the top half of the rectangle or the bottom half of the rectangle and depending on which, does something accordingly.

So maybe something like

```
if(Intersector.overlaps(circle, rectangle.getHeight() - rectangle.getHeight() / 2)){
    do something
}
```

But unfortunately that would return a float, which the intersect class does not accept.

Any ideas on how to go about accomplishing this would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Keep a reusable extra rectangle instance:

private final Rectangle tmp = new Rectangle();

When your circle intersects Rectangle A you care about, then you can set the temporary rectangle to be the top half of Rectangle A and check that for a collision. The result tells you if the top or the bottom was where the collision happened. (But the top would also register a collision if the circle intersects both top and bottom halves, so keep that in mind.)

```
if(Intersector.overlaps(circle, rectangle)){
    tmp.set(rectangle.x, rectangle.y + rectangle.height/2, rectangle.width, rectangle.height/2);
    if (Intersector.overlaps(circle, tmp){
        //top half (or both top and bottom) hit
    } else {
        //bottom half hit
    }
}
```

Comment: Worked like a charm. Thanks.